# My dynamically placed content is not displaying correctly

Tags: php, html, css, dynamic

I am creating a forum website and my dynamically placed links are ignoring the css I assign them. I want the links to display like this:

```
    Music

    Movies

    Technology

    Gaming
```

(I just want padding)

Yet when I style them they display like this:

Music

Movies

Technology

Gaming

Here's my code:

```
<?php
//Select and order the content from forum_sections in ascending order 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_section ORDER BY ordered ASC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());

$displayList = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $sectionID = $row["id"];
    $sectionTitle = $row["title"];
    $displayList .= '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'" class="forum_links" id='.$sectionID.'>'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br />';
}
?>
```

And here is my css:

```
.forum_links {
    padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I don't even know if you CAN style dynamic content, just thought I could try.

PS: If you could show me how to put all this in a table and each link being a table row that would be most appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If u can paste the generated html from DOM and maybe u can even see if all ur files are loaded and/or markup is overridden by other rules ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your `$displayList` variable:

```
$displayList .= '<table id="theList">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $sectionID = $row["id"];
  $sectionTitle = $row["title"];
  $displayList .= '<tr><td>';
  $displayList .= '<a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'" class="forum_links" id='.$sectionID.'>'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br />';
  $displayList .= '</td></tr>';
}
$displayList .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to format your data into a table, add the `tr` and `td` elements to your generated php then place it in a table. Something like this should work:

PHP

```
$displayList .= '<tr><td><a href="section.php?id='.$sectionID.'" class="forum_links" id='.$sectionID.'>'.$sectionTitle.'</a><br /></td></tr>';
```

HTML

```
<table><?php echo $displayList; ?></table>
```

Also, any CSS styles you assign to the table should work as well, although CSS and tables don't always play nice together.